# Read NDEF Message with a Card Reader and C#

Tags: c#, ndef

I am working with an ACR 1251 reader for quite some time and in these days I have gained some knowledge about NFC, different card types mainly Mifare Ultralight and Mifare Classic. I am till now able to read all data from a Ultralight Tag.
Problem:
After reading all data from a tag I want to read the message and Record contained in it. Ideally a library that can parse the given message. Please note I have tried the NdefLibrary to parse a message by reading all data from tag but somehow it didn't work :(
Any help to progress further will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check out Arduino NFC shields, they come with some good libraries for reading NFC cards. Perhaps you can get something out of that..

Comment: NdefLibrary should work fine. However, there's a layer between NdefLibrary and the raw tag: the [NFC Forum](http://www.nfc-forum/) Tag Operation specifications. So you would need to implement those specifications (or at least the Type 2 Tag Operation, if you want to support MF Ultralight) in order to read the proper memory locations that contain the NDEF data.